# confused about the time complexity of the follwing func. A good explanation would be helpful

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

> If the the first loop runs for n+1 times. 
>   second loop runs for n(n+1) times. 
>   third loop will run for ??? it has n^2+1 one relation with with with the second loop i guess but   how about with the first one

```
somefunction(n) {  
 c = 0      
 for (i = 1 to n*n)          
   for (j = 1 to n)               
     for (k = 1 to 2*j)                    
        c = c+1     
  return c 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first loop has `O(n**2)` iterations.

The second loop has `O(n)` iterations.

The third loop has `O(n)` iterations as well, since `j` is steadily increasing towards `n`.

(It's a little easier to see if you sum up the number of times `c = c + 1` executes for the two inner loops combined. The inner loop runs 2 times for `j = 1`, 4 for `j = 2`, ..., and `2*n` times for `j = n`. 2 + 4 + .. + 2*n = O(n**2).)

You can then (loosely speaking) multiply the three values together to get a total bound of O(n**4).